# How to write a get and set method for array to access a private array

Tags: c++, c++11

Not sure if there is already an explanation regarding creating a get and set method for array but I cant find it there for I am here asking you experts. I am trying to unfriend the istream and ostream as per my assignment. but I cant figure out how to access `private Result Results[MAXRESULTUNIT]`. Have been on google for the past few days trying figure this out. Hopefully someone can help guide me along with this problem of mine.

```
// REGIST.H - Registration class definition
// author KRI
// modified smr

#ifndef REGIST_H
#define REGIST_H


#include <iostream>
#include "Result.h"

using namespace std;

const int MAXRESULTUNIT = 1000;

class Registration
{
public:
    Registration();
    Registration(long &R_studentID, int &R_Semester);

    void SetStudentID(const long &R_studentID);
    void GetStudentID(long &R_studentID) const;
    void SetSemester(const int &R_Semester);
    void GetSemester(int &R_Semester) const;
    void SetCount(int &R_Count);
    int GetCredits() const;
    int GetCount() const;
    int GetArray(); // please ignore this. was just trying something based on what i found on google (not working)
  
private:
    long studentId;             // student ID number
    int semester;          // semester year, number
    int count;             // number of courses
    Result Results[MAXRESULTUNIT]; // array of courses
};
istream & operator >>( istream & input,Registration & R );
ostream & operator <<( ostream & os,const Registration & R);
#endif
```

Did some editing, was trying to create a get and set method for the array so that I can call it since its private.

Comment: the question is unclear. The array is already `private` and not accessible from outside the class. That is what usually is refered to as encapsulation

Comment: are you asking how to implement `operator>>` and `operator<<`  to print the array elements?

Comment: Getter functions with out-parameters and setters with modifiable reference parameters?? Is that really what you are being taught?

Comment: @user17732522 hi sir, please ignore that GetArray() was trying something from what i found on the internet

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes sir, am trying to create a get and set method so that i can output the array

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe start with a member function with the signature `Result const& GetResult(int idx) const;`?

Comment: What's the point of `private` members if you make them `public` via getters and setters? That's not encapsulation, that's boilerplate code.

Comment: Yes, before adding all the boilerplate it can be useful to consider what it is to be used for. For example `SetStudentID`. Using that you can first pass some courses and then call `SetStudentID` to transfer the credits to some other student. Is that a use case we want to support?